# How to get all groups on a local machine with managed code (no P/Invoke)

Tags: c#, .net, windows

So I was looking on SO for the answer to this question and it seemed as everything I came across was for Active Directory or something similar. There were no examples for this for the local machine.

Basically the goal here is to get all the user groups in the system. The same ones you'd see if you launch Computer Management, traverse to System Tools > Local Users and Groups > Groups

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get a list of local machine groups / users when machine is not in active directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33923951/how-to-get-a-list-of-local-machine-groups-users-when-machine-is-not-in-active)

Comment: i searched for about an hour and never came across that question/answer. while i agree the question is the same the answers are completely different.

changed my question title

Comment: you could as well add your answer to the duplicate, its a good thing to update aged questions with state-of-the-art approaches.

Answer (score 0):

```
using (PrincipalContext context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Machine))
{
    using (GroupPrincipal groupPrincipal = new GroupPrincipal(context))
    {
        groupPrincipal.Name = "*";

        PrincipalSearcher principalSearcher = new PrincipalSearcher();
        principalSearcher.QueryFilter = groupPrincipal;
        PrincipalSearchResult<Principal> groupList = principalSearcher.FindAll();

        foreach (Principal group in groupList)
        {
            // Do something with info
        }
   }
}
```